# How to do logging for errors only in kdb? (not results)

Tags: logging, kdb

I would like to write down all errors to a log file but not results from queries. I tried this in command line:

```
q test.q >kdb.log
```

However it logs everything even those data from results. I only want to log errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also do it from the command line:

```
q test.q 1>stdout.log 2>stderr.log
```

Comment: Thanks, if I want to write to the log. how should I do it. I tried h:hopen `:stderr.log; h"test"; how can i make next entries in different line? also, I wrote a function: logWrite:{[para]h:hopen `:stderr.log; h"para"}; it doesnt work cuz para is inside the quotation mark. Do you know how I can pass the parameter? Thanks, Terry

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect stdout and/or stderr: http://code.kx.com/q/ref/syscmds/#1-2-redirect

Comment: You may also want to override the IPC event handlers http://www.timestored.com/kdb-guides/interprocess-communication#messageHandlers to log remote calls etc.